# Generate symmetric positive definite matrix with a pre-specified sparsity pattern

Tags: correlation, matrix, sparse, correlation-matrix

I am trying to generate a correlation matrix $p\times p$ (symmetric p.s.d) with a pre-specified sparsity structure (specified by a graph on $p$ nodes). The nodes that are connected in the graph have correlation $\rho \sim U(0,1)$, rest all are 0 and the diagonal is all 1.

I have tried generating this matrix several times but only rarely get a valid correlation matrix.

Is there a way that I can assure a correlation matrix w.h.p? Note that I can only have positive correlation so $\rho \sim U(-1,1)$ etc. is not an option.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the function nearPD of the package Matrix in R can help.

Comment: What is your measure of sparsity that is fixed for you? Should your data be binary or nonnegative continuous?

Comment: @niandra82: nearPD is no good as it will destroy the sparsity of the matrix.

Comment: @ttnphns: As I mentioned, the non-zero entries are distributed uniform(0,1), hence they are non-negative continuous.

Comment: What about using the Cholesky decomposition?  First generate an upper triangular matrix $T$ with all non-negative values and treat $T^TT$ as a covariance matrix. Then where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of standard deviation, your correlation matrix will be $D^{-1}T^TTD^{-1}$.  The level of sparsity in $T$ will directly effect that of the correlation matrix via the matrix multiplication.  Though it's a crude starting point, it is a starting point nonetheless.  Also it would be easier if you only specified the bounds for non-zero entries rather than the uniformity. May this be relaxed?

Comment: In general there are no such matrix distributions as described in this question. Consider, for instance, the $3\times 3$ case with three coefficients $\rho,\sigma,\tau$. If $\tau=0$ and $\rho\gt 0, \sigma\gt 0$, then $\rho^2+\sigma^2\lt 1$ if and only if the matrix is positive definite. But then you cannot have both $\rho\sim U(0,1)$ and $\sigma\sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld I think it will be really hard to specify the sparsity that way.

Comment: @whuber Hmm, makes sense! Put another way, is there any way of making distributional assumptions, maybe different for $\rho$ and $\sigma$ that could lead to the matrix being p.d?

Comment: Then why not generate the correlation matrix first.  Then create a symetric index for that matrix where you force the indexed elements to 0.  Sparcity would be specified by the size of the index and you can incorperate  randommess through a function like sample in r.  No matter how many off diagonal elements you force to 0, the matix will still be p.d.

Comment: Sure. For instance, adopt a distribution on the space of all p-d matrices and restrict it to those satisfying the specified equalities (for the zero coefficients) and inequalities (for the positive coefficients). This is the direction @ZacharyBlumenfeld was suggesting you go (in the last line of his comment).

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld Thanks! If I understand correctly what you mean, I generated a symmetric matrix with all its entries u(0,1). I should keep on generating such matrices in a loop till I get one which is p.d. Once I get a p.d. matrix, I should set to zero all the entries that I want to, and the resulting matrix should still be p.d? It turns out that even the process of generating non-sparse uniform symmetric matrices also rarely generates p.d. matrix, so its time consuming. I feel that starting from Cholesky decomp. would be a surer way, but then the $T^{\top}T$ won't be u(0,1). Any thoughts?

Comment: @whuber I guess a potential distribution over p.d. matrices could be Wishart, but then again, even it requires a p.d. matrix as a parameter. Are there others?

Comment: There are a huge number of such distributions.  For instance, if $(A,D)$ is *any* bivariate distribution of positive random variables, then $$\pmatrix{A&0\\0&D}$$ is a sparse $2\times 2$ positive definite matrix. And that's just the simplest nontrivial situation!

Comment: I've got a similar question out on stan-users (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/stan-users/general/TqZxEbdiClM). I thought I could use the rejection "feature" of MCMC (or HMC) to knock out non-positive definite matrices when they occurred. I was wrong; turns out there's this pesky business about priors integrating to one.

Answer (score 2):

Close but no cigar for @Rodrigo de Azevedo.

The solution is to use semidefinite programming to find the maximum value, $\rho_{max}$, and the minimum value (subject to being nonnegative), $\rho_{min}$, of $\rho$ such that the correlation matrix with prescribed sparsity pattern is positive semidefinite (psd).  All values of $\rho$ such that $\rho_{max}\le \rho \le \rho_{max}$, will produce psd matrices (exercise for reader)

Therefore, you must either choose a distribution of $\rho$ which can only take values in $[\rho_{max},\rho_{max}]$, or you must use acceptance/rejection and reject any generated values of $\rho$ which do not produce a psd matrix.

Example for a 4 by 4 matrix using YALMIP under MATLAB

```
sdpvar rho % declare rho to be a scalar variable
% find maximum value of rho (by minimizing -rho) subject to prescribed matrix being psd.
optimize([1 0 rho 0;0 1 rho 0;rho rho 1 rho;0 0 rho 1] >= 0,-rho) 
% find minimum value of rho subject to prescribed matrix being psd and rho being >= 0.
optimize([[1 0 rho 0;0 1 rho 0;rho rho 1 rho;0 0 rho 1] >= 0,rho >= 0],rho)
```

Results: maximum rho = 0.57735, minimum rho = 0.  It is readily apparent that zero will be the minimum value of rho subject to rho being nonegative and the prescribed matrix being psd, regardless of dimension or sparsity pattern. Therefore, it is unnecessary to run the semidefinite optimization to find the minimum nonnegative value of $\rho$.

Comment: This is an interesting interpretation of the question: it assumes all nonzero off-diagonal coefficients are equal (thereby tremendously simplifying the problem).  It's not clear whether that was the intended interpretation, or whether all nonzero off-diagonal coefficients are supposed to be *independent realizations* from a common distribution.

Comment: That is the interpretation I made. Now that you mention it, I could see a different interpretation being possible. At least my interpretation has the virtue of resulting in a fairly well-defined problem. I suppose a problem can be formulated, whose solution I have not researched, to find the maximum value of ρ such that all non-zero off-diagonal elements of one triangle of the correlation matrix can be filled in with not necessarily equal nonnegative values ≤ that value, and necessarily make the fully populated matrix be psd.

Answer (score 0):

A correlation matrix is symmetric, positive semidefinite, and has $1$'s on its main diagonal. One can find a $n \times n$ correlation matrix by solving the following **semidefinite program** (SDP) where the objective function is arbitrary, say, the zero function

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm \langle \mathrm O_n, \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & x_{11} = x_{22} = \cdots = x_{nn} = 1\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

If one has additional constraints, such as sparsity constraints

$$x_{ij} = 0 \text{ for all } (i,j) \in \mathcal Z \subset [n] \times [n]$$

and non-negativity constraints, $\mathrm X \geq \mathrm O_n$, then one solves the following SDP

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm \langle \mathrm O_n, \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & x_{11} = x_{22} = \cdots = x_{nn} = 1\\ & x_{ij} = 0 \text{ for all } (i,j) \in \mathcal Z \subset [n] \times [n]\\ & \mathrm X \geq \mathrm O_n\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

---

**A $3 \times 3$ example**

Suppose we want to have $x_{13} = 0$ and $x_{12}, x_{23} \geq 0$. Here's a MATLAB + [CVX](http://cvxr.com) script,

```
cvx_begin sdp

    variable X(3,3) symmetric

    minimize( trace(zeros(3,3)*X) )
    subject to

        % put ones on the main diagonal
        X(1,1)==1
        X(2,2)==1
        X(3,3)==1

        % put a zero in the northeast and southwest corners
        X(1,3)==0

        % impose nonnegativity
        X(1,2)>=0
        X(2,3)>=0

        % impose positive semidefiniteness
        X >= 0

cvx_end
```

Running the script,

```
Calling sedumi: 8 variables, 6 equality constraints
------------------------------------------------------------
SeDuMi 1.21 by AdvOL, 2005-2008 and Jos F. Sturm, 1998-2003.
Alg = 2: xz-corrector, Adaptive Step-Differentiation, theta = 0.250, beta = 0.500
eqs m = 6, order n = 6, dim = 12, blocks = 2
nnz(A) = 8 + 0, nnz(ADA) = 36, nnz(L) = 21
 it :     b*y       gap    delta  rate   t/tP*  t/tD*   feas cg cg  prec
  0 :            3.00E+000 0.000
  1 : -1.18E-001 6.45E-001 0.000 0.2150 0.9000 0.9000   1.86  1  1  1.2E+000
  2 : -6.89E-004 2.25E-002 0.000 0.0349 0.9900 0.9900   1.52  1  1  3.5E-001
  3 : -6.48E-009 9.72E-007 0.097 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000   1.01  1  1  3.8E-006
  4 : -3.05E-010 2.15E-009 0.000 0.0022 0.9990 0.9990   1.00  1  1  1.5E-007
  5 : -2.93E-016 5.06E-015 0.000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000   1.00  1  1  3.2E-013

iter seconds digits       c*x               b*y
  5      0.3   5.8  0.0000000000e+000 -2.9302886987e-016
|Ax-b| =  1.7e-015, [Ay-c]_+ =  6.1E-016, |x|= 2.0e+000, |y|= 1.5e-015

Detailed timing (sec)
   Pre          IPM          Post
1.563E-001    2.500E-001    1.094E-001    
Max-norms: ||b||=1, ||c|| = 0,
Cholesky |add|=0, |skip| = 0, ||L.L|| = 1.
------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Solved
Optimal value (cvx_optval): +0
```

Let's see what solution CVX found,

```
>> X

X =

    1.0000    0.4143         0
    0.4143    1.0000    0.4143
         0    0.4143    1.0000
```

Is this matrix positive semidefinite? Positive definite?

```
>> rank(X)

ans =

     3

>> eigs(X)

ans =

    1.5860
    1.0000
    0.4140
```

It is positive definite, as expected. We can find positive semidefinite correlation matrices by choosing a nonzero (linear) objective function.

Comment: Because on this site "generate" would be understood to mean "draw from a random distribution," could you explain how your code produces random correlation matrices and indicate what distribution they follow?

Comment: @whuber The OP is asking for the impossible. You commented on that on January 1, 2015. If you want to generate random correlation matrices, then generate a random square matrix and use it in the objective function in the semidefinite program above. Or, generate realizations of a random variable that is uniform over the cube $$[-1,1]^{\binom{n}{2}}$$ put them in the off-diagonal entries of (correlation) matrices with $1$'s on the main diagonal, and discard the ones that aren't positive semidefinite. If there are nonnegativity constraints, then uniformly sample the cube $$[0,1]^{\binom{n}{2}}$$

Comment: The impossibility was due to the request to make the marginal distributions uniform.  The response by the OP in the comment thread was "is there any way of making distributional assumptions, maybe different for ρ and σ that could lead to the matrix being p.d?"

Comment: @whuber Here's the [3D elliptope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFHwa.png) [png], which maps to the set of $3 \times 3$ correlation matrices. What the OP wants is to intersect the elliptope with the nonnegative octant, then intersect it with planes of the form $x_{ij} = 0$. If the matrix is $\succ 0$, then it must be in the **interior** of the elliptope. Using SDP with nonzero objective functions, one can sample the **surface** of the elliptope. As the elliptope is convex, convex combinations of surface points will also map to correlation matrices.

Comment: That's an excellent way to describe the situation.

Comment: @whuber My previous comment was a bit sloppy and I can no longer edit it. After intersecting the 3D elliptope with the nonnegative octant and then with $x_{13} = 0$, one obtains one of the *flat* faces of the cut elliptope. This face is not an elliptope itself, but it is a **spectrahedron**. One could try to generate a uniform distribution over this spectrahedron. I have no idea how, however.

Comment: @whuber The elliptope is contained inside a hypercube. Last weekend, I posted a [question on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1971193/339790) on the 3D elliptope. The percentage of the volume of the cube it takes is $\approx 61\%$. I suspect that as the dimension of the correlation matrices grows, the percentage of the volume of the hypercube taken by the elliptope becomes smaller and smaller. I may be wrong, though. If I am correct, then using a uniform distribution over the hypercube and discarding realizations that are not PSD is not practical if the matrices are large.

Comment: You are correct about how the relative volumes shrink.  That is precisely why this is a difficult problem.